# Measure elapsed time from fixed datetime

Tags: python-datetime

I am trying to measure how many minutes have elapsed from the time I turn my code from a fixed time, lets say 8:30 am of that day. If I turn my code on at 12am it should see that 210 minutes have elapsed. Any suggestions would help greatly. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import the `datetime` module, which has a class with the same name, with method `datetime.datetime.now()`.

This returns an object representing the time when it is called.

This object has the method `replace()`, which can be used to 'change' the time to 8:30, if you call it like so - `replace(hour=8, minute=30)`.

You can then create another similar object but without replacing the time, then you can simply subtract the first from the second to get the elapsed time as a datetime object.

This will then have `elapsed_time.seconds` to give you the time change in seconds, which can be divided by 60 if you want for the time in minutes.

Example

```py
import datetime

time_A = datetime.datetime.now()
time_A = time_A.replace(hour=8, minute=30)

time_B = datetime.datetime.now()

elapsed_time = time_B - time_A

print(elapsed_time.seconds, "seconds have passed since 8:30 this morning")
```

If you wanted this for a specific timezone, you can add or subtract the offset from your current timezone. So if you are for example, 5 hours ahead of CST, you can have it get the difference from 3:30 instead.

Comment: Respectfully, I dont think that is the question I asked. I need the amount of minutes elapsed from the time i turn my code to fixed value of time 8:30 am CST.  This is so I can do some real time analysis of stocks, and verify that my data collected is complete compared to how much time has passed in the market.

Comment: @jon sorry about that, I've edited the whole thing to hopefully better reflect what you've asked :)